# What does Google Wallet attractive pricing really mean?

Tags: android-pay

It says:"Attractive pricing: the most favorable of 5% or 1.9% + 30c (USD) per transaction is automatically applied."

Is the pricing attractive for me or for Google?

```
 So for $1 how much will I get and how much google? 

 Will I get it on 5% schema(Me=95cents, Google=5cents ) or 1.9%+30c (Me=68cents, Google=32)?
```

Comment: What has this to do with programming?

Comment: it has to do with developers that are using gWallet

Comment: `Attractive pricing` I believe applies to you as a developer receiving money.  So for `1` Dollar you would only pay `5 cents`.  The scenario that is cheaper for you will be applied on every transaction.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about pricing structures.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's attractive to you. Developers complained to Google that 5% charge for microtransactions (small transaction) was attractive (i.e. beneficial) to them (the developers), but that as amount increase, they don't want to pay 5% which is a lot.

So they **changed their pricing to benefit you, the developers** and call it "Attractive Pricing". With this new pricing, you could be charged **as low as 1.9%** (and **not the blanket 5%**) for larger amount transactions. Here's more details on this.

Via: [Updates to Google Wallet for digital goods including attractive pricing and subscriptions support.](http://googlecommerce.blogspot.com/2012/07/updates-to-google-wallet-for-digital.html)

> First, we’ve heard feedback from developers that 5% transaction fees
>   are great for microtransactions but not as attractive for larger
>   transactions with higher order value. **To improve your experience**
>   **selling higher priced items**, we’re introducing 1.9% + $0.30 (or local
>   equivalent) pricing in addition to the current 5%. Google will apply
>   the option **that charges you the lower of the two possible transaction**
>   **fees for that order**. Learn more and see examples of when each pricing
>   option will apply in the Help Center.